# Get outputs instance_id from loop another module terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to get instance id for my module ec2 when I create using for_each and I need instance_id for my module tgroup to assign or join new instance in specific target group.

My module ec2

```
resource "aws_instance" "ProductionServer" {
    count                       = length(var.SubnetServer)
    ami                         = module.CreateAMI.AMIId.id
    instance_type               = var.TypeServer
    subnet_id                   = var.SubnetServer[count.index]
}
```

ec2/outputs.tf

```
output "InstanceId" {
    value = aws_instance.ProductionServer
    description = "get value id"
  
}
```

and my module tgroup

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "TgProdRegister" {
    for_each         = module.GetInstanceId.InstanceId.id
    target_group_arn = var.TgroupArn
    target_id        = each.value
    port             = var.TgPort 

    depends_on = [ module.GetInstanceId ]
  
}
```

and **GetInstanceId** is refer to module ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `count` for the instances, to return their ids as a **list**, you would have to do:

```
output "InstanceId" {
    value = aws_instance.ProductionServer[*].id
    description = "get value id"
}
```

Then for the target groups it would be:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "TgProdRegister" {
    count            = length(module.GetInstanceId)
    target_group_arn = var.TgroupArn
    target_id        = module.GetInstanceId.InstanceId[count.index]
    port             = var.TgPort 
}
```

Buy the way you should consider placing your instances in auto-scaling groups (ASG) if possible.

Comment: hai @Marcin, thanks for your answer before, its work for me if my variable list subnet is => 3 but if its not, i get error like this. is there still something missing in my variable ?


`Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on tgroup/tgroup.tf line 8, in resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "TgProdRegister":
│    8:     target_id        = module.GetInstanceId.InstanceId[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 2
│     │ module.GetInstanceId.InstanceId is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Comment: @Noobers "it not like that condition " - sorry, I don't understand. Your question does not have any conditions. This seems as a new issue, and I would suggest making new question with the new code and the "condition" that you have.

Comment: sorry @Marcin for my mistake, i mean if insert my list subnet like 
`SubnetServer = ["subnet-08xxx","subnet-082xxxx","subnet-084xxxx" ]` its worked for me but if its my list subnet just 2 subnet like 
`SubnetServer = ["subnet-08xxx","subnet-082xxxx" ]`
then i got the error as above

Comment: @Noobers You can do `element(var.SubnetServer, count.index)`